# 'str' object is not callable for GDAL proximity

Tags: python, string, gis, gdal

I am very new to GDAL library (trying it as of today actually) and I have a hard time figuring out what I'm doing wrong here. I am trying to execute the 'proximity' function from GDAL, but keep getting the ''str' object is not callable' error message.
Can anyone indicate me what I'm doing wrong.

```
import os
from osgeo import gdal, osr
gdal_proximity = "C:\\anaconda3\\envs\\geo_py37\\Scripts\\gdal_proximity.py"


proximityInput = gdal.Open(folderPath + os.sep + "proximity_input.tif")
outputTemplate = gdal.Open(folderPath + os.sep + "output_template.tif")

######## Raster properties based on 'outputTemplate' ################
projection = outputTemplate.GetProjection()
ncols = outputTemplate.RasterXSize
nrows = outputTemplate.RasterYSize
bandCount = outputTemplate.RasterCount
upx, xres, xskew, upy, yskew, yres = outputTemplate.GetGeoTransform()
#####################################################################

driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('Gtiff')
proximityOutput = driver.Create(folderPath + os.sep + "proximity_output.tif", ncols, nrows, bandCount, gdal.GDT_Float32)
proximityOutput.SetGeoTransform([upx, xres, xskew, upy, yskew, yres])
proximityOutputPrj = distanceRaster.SetProjection(projection)

gdal_proximity (proximityInput, proximityOutputPrj)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/antoi/.PyCharmCE2019.3/config/scratches/Radial_Linear_Mean.py", line 22, in <module>
    gdal_proximity(proximityInput, proximityOutputPrj)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: ***"keep getting the ''str' object is not callable' error message."***: [Edit] your question and show the **Full Traceback**

Answer (score 0):

in your third line of code you set (overwrite) `gdal_proximity` to be the following string

```
gdal_proximity = "C:\\anaconda3\\envs\\geo_py37\\Scripts\\gdal_proximity.py"
```

You then try to call it as a function.

```
gdal_proximity (proximityInput, proximityOutputPrj)
```

which triggers your error because its not a function, its a string, so is not callable as a function.

Comment: Alright, thanks! I foolishly thought that I could bypass the environment settings that I can't seem to get my head around. When I remove that line, I always get : NameError: name 'gdal_proximity' is not defined. I'll work on my environment settings and figure it out. Thanks !

Comment: I dont know too much about `gdal_proximity` but if you want to use a function in a script you have to import it first